# How to import PhotoSwipe with Rails and Importmap

Tags: ruby-on-rails, photoswipe, import-maps

I've pinned photoswipe:

```
./bin/importmap pin photoswipe --download
```

in app/javascript/application.js I've added

```
import PhotoSwipeLightbox from 'photoswipe'
document.addEventListener("turbo:load", function() {
  const lightbox = new PhotoSwipeLightbox({
    gallery: '#existing-files',
    children: '.gal',
    pswpModule: () => import('photoswipe')
  });
  lightbox.init();
});
```

The lightbox opens straight away on page load but the image is missing. pswpModule: () => import('photoswipe') doesn't appear to work but no error is given.

Answer (score 2):

I worked it out. I needed:

```
./bin/importmap pin photoswipe --download
./bin/importmap pin photoswipe/lightbox --download
```

then

```
import PhotoSwipeLightbox from 'photoswipe/lightbox'
```